# Stacking Monk and Paragon classes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk

Can a Monk take Racial Paragon levels and then take Monk levels again without taking the feat for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**

Racial paragon classes don't have any special exemption clauses for Monks or Paladins, and despite their short length are treated by the game as being base classes, as demonstrated here by the SRD:

> Like the fighter, the wizard, and the other standard character classes, the racial paragon classes have no prerequisites (other than being a member of the appropriate race). Paragon class levels can be taken any time a character gains a new level, even at 1st level (in which case they receive four times the normal number of skill points gained at each succeeding level). A character can multiclass freely between standard character classes, prestige classes for which he or she qualifies, and the character's appropriate racial paragon class.

Though racial paragon classes call out a specific exemption from multiclassing XP penalties (a godsend, by the way, for anyone interested in them), nowhere in their description ([here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/racialParagonClasses.htm)) do they call out an exception to the multiclassing rules for Monk and/or Paladin.

Your DM is able to/should most definitely house rule away the multiclassing rules on Monk, but by RAW, them's the breaks.